# How to batch download still frames from youtube videos?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, python, youtube, youtube-dl

I am working on a project that requires running analyses on around 20k videos hosted on youtube.com. For my analyses, I need 3-5 screenshots of each video, at different points in the video.

I know how to use youtube-dl, but I do not want to download an entire video to then take screenshots with ffmpeg. I would prefer to download the screenshots directly without downloading the entire video. I also know how to download a video's thumbnail in maximum quality, but I would need 3-5 screenshots.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be possible, but it's not so easy. You could try to modify `youtube-dl`'s behavior to not actually download *all* video segments from YouTube's servers, but only select ones. If you inspect what the program does by using the `--print-traffic` option, you'll see that it first queries the video metadata (the DASH MPD manifest via `/get_video_info`) and then downloads individual chunks listed in that manifest using byte range requests. From those select downloaded chunks, you should be able to fetch a thumbnail via ffmpeg.

Comment: The responsible code for downloading individual video fragments should be here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/e06632e3fe25036b804a62469bb18fa4c37e3368/youtube_dl/downloader/dash.py#L11